# Uploading an image to friends' wall using Graph API

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know the Graph API equivalent of the following action :

Go to a friend's profile page, click on "Add Photo" on their wall, then "Upload Photo".

I can upload images to my own wall and to my own albums, and I can also post messages and links to my friends' feed, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do it setting a "target_id" parameter, and uploading the image to "graph.facebook.com/me/photos". Then it does show up exactly as if it had been done the manual way.

The only thing I'm not sure about is if "target_id" is some legacy parameter from the REST API that will become unsupported in the future...

Answer (score 2):

I believe that process adds a photo to one of *your* albums; then attaches that to a Post on your friend's 'feed' connection

You can find documentation for both of those steps on the developer site:
Upload Photo: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos
Post on wall: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts - see the 'object_attachment' parameter here

Comment: That's pretty close. I don't think I would've tried object_attachment. Thanks! 

But here's what I'm getting https://picasaweb.google.com/114066477118649763567/Foils?authkey=Gv1sRgCJH5vNe-u9ChOg#5733501234601824818. The top one is through the app, the bottom one is manual. And if I look at the objects using the Graph API Explorer, the one that is added manually has a "story" parameter. I would like to replicate that (if possible).

Comment: I'm not sure that's actually possible, happy to be corrected, but i don't think i've ever seen it done